# Mapkick Gem Mapbox marker icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hope someone can help me.

I'm currently using the mapbox via the mapkick gem to place pins on the map with a location.

Now facing an issue when trying to pass an SVG URL as an icon marker in my Rails application. I've tried several solutions, but none seem to work correctly.

```
<%= js_map [{ latitude: 37.7829,
longitude: -122.4190,
label: "Hot Chicken Takeover",
tooltip: "5 stars",
icon: ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("icon_user_logged_in.svg")
}],
style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
zoom: 9,
controls: true, id: "cities-map", width: "1250px", height: "600px", tooltips: {hover: false, html: true} %>
```

Am I using the icon attribute correctly?

documentation: https://chartkick.com/mapkick

According to this "issue" https://github.com/ankane/mapkick/issues/8 the gem does not yet support this feature. When I use icon attribute, the marker icon disappears. Maybe someone has done some trick or looked for another solution?

Comment: If you're inlining this somewhere in your view why are you calling `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path` instead of just calling the normal `asset_path` helper on the view context?

Comment: Personally I would just skip the gem. Integrating Rails and Mapbox is not difficult and you don't have to live with the questionable design decions made to make it "simple".

Comment: thanks for the comment. good idea, but i dont have enough experience for that :( I should take a look at the documentation